# Trying to get a result set from a table with a joined table using Criteria API in Java

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have three mapped entities, an item, a user and a company.
There is a table that defines the user and their relationship to the company (for permissions)

I'm trying to find all of these items that are either owned by the user, or owned by companies that they have permission to view / edit.

I can get the query to work easily in native SQL, I just cannot get it to work with criteria builder. It will have dynamic filters and ordering, so using native queries gets messy with string concatenation.

```java
@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private Integer itemId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "company_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Company companyId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Users userId;

    ... getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class CompanyUsers implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "company_user_id")
    private Integer companyUserId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "edit_company")
    private boolean editCompany;
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "company_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Company companyId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Users userId;

    ... getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private Integer companyId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "companyId")
    private Collection<CompanyUsers> companyUsersCollection;

    ...getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class Users implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 128)
    @Column(name = "email_address")
    private String emailAddress;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<Item> itemCollection;    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<CompanyUsers> companyUsersCollection;

    ...getters and setters...

/*
Then the attempt and getting this right with Criteria Builder.
*/

public List<Item> findAllItem(Users selectedUser, int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Item> cq = cb.createQuery(Item.class);

        Root<Item> item = cq.from(Item.class);
        CriteriaQuery<Item> select = cq.select(item);
        Subquery<CompanyUsers> subquery = cq.subquery(CompanyUsers.class);
        Root<CompanyUsers> companyUsers = subquery.from(CompanyUsers.class);
        subquery.select(companyUsers)
                .distinct(true)
                .where(cb.equal(companyUsers.get("userId"), selectedUser));

        if (sortField == null) {
            sortField = "itemId";
        }

        if (sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)) {
            cq.orderBy(cb.asc(item.get(sortField)));
        } else if (sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.DESCENDING)) {
            cq.orderBy(cb.desc(item.get(sortField)));
        }

        List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
        predicateList.add(cb.equal(item.get("userId"), selectedUser));
        predicateList.add(cb.in(item.get("companyId")).value(subquery));

        filters.entrySet().forEach((filter) -> {
            if (filter.getKey().equals("itemStatus") || filter.getKey().equals("itemId")) {
                predicateList.add(cb.equal(item.get(filter.getKey()), filter.getValue().toString()));
            } else {
                predicateList.add(cb.like(item.get(filter.getKey()), "%" + filter.getValue().toString() + "%"));
            }
        });

        Predicate[] predicateArray = predicateList.stream().toArray(Predicate[]::new);

        cq.where(predicateArray);

        TypedQuery<Item> typedQuery = em.createQuery(select);
        if (first >= 0) {
            typedQuery.setFirstResult(first);
        }
        if (pageSize >= 0) {
            typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        }

        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }
```

I've not included all the column names here, but there are more.

This produces the following sql:

```sql
SELECT t0.title AS a2, t0.item_id AS a1 FROM item t0, company_users t1 WHERE ((t0.user_id = ?) AND (t1.user_id = ?)) ORDER BY t0.item_id ASC LIMIT ?, ?
```

Which is close to either of the following:

```sql
select title, item_id, cu.company_id from item s left join company_users as cu on cu.company_id = s.company_id where s.user_id = 2 or cu.user_id = 2;
```

or

```sql
select title,item_id from item s where s.user_id = 2 or s.company_id in (select company_id from company_users where user_id = 2) ;
```

The above two native queries are what I'm trying to achieve. I cannot get the criteria builder to work using either a Join or Subquery.

Comment: So, after two days of banging my head on the table, I've given up on criteria builder. I've now rather just used em.createQuery - I'll post the solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public List<Item> findAllItem(Users selectedUser, int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

        ArrayList<String> filterItems = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        filters.entrySet().forEach((filter) -> {
                switch (filter.getKey()) {
                    case "userStatus":
                        filterItems.add(" AND s.statusType = :statusType");
                        parameterMap.put("statusType", (String) filter.getValue());
                        break;
                    case "title":
                        filterItems.add(" AND s.title like :title");
                        parameterMap.put("title", "%" + (String) filter.getValue() + "%");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
        }


        String sortDirection;
        if (sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)) {
            sortDirection = "ASC";
        } else {
            sortDirection = "DESC";
        }

        String sortString;
        if (sortField == null) {
            sortString = "s.itemId";
        } else {
            switch (sortField) {
                case "title":
                    sortString = "s.title";
                    break;
                case "statusType":
                    sortString = "s.statusType";
                    break;
                case "startDate":
                    sortString = "s.startDate";
                    break;
                case "endDate":
                    sortString = "s.endDate";
                    break;
                default:
                    sortString = "s.itemId";
                    break;
            }
        }

        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s from Item s WHERE (s.userId = :userId or s.companyId in "
                + "(SELECT cu.companyId from CompanyUsers cu WHERE cu.userId = :userId))"
                + String.join(" ", filterItems)
                + " ORDER BY " + sortString + " " + sortDirection,
                 Item.class);

        query.setParameter("userId", selectedUser);
        for (String key : parameterMap.keySet()) {
            query.setParameter(key, parameterMap.get(key));
        }

        if (first >= 0) {
            query.setFirstResult(first);
        }
        if (pageSize >= 0) {
            query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        }
        List<Item> result = query.getResultList();
        return result;
    }
```